# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Show on Hover, hide on onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, twitter-bootstrap

I changed the bootstrab.js (just replaced click with hover):

```
  $(function () {
    $('body').on('hover.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })
  })
```

Now i want the content-tab to close when you are not hovering over the tab or content.

How do i do this?

Comment: fyi, this will work bad on mobile touch devices since there is no hover :o

Comment: On mobile browsers hover is automatically replaced by click. Together with a manual close button its pretty smooth. Just tested it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: something like the below

```
var timer;

$('tab_element').hover(
    function(){ //hover
        // clear timer first
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // then show the content
    },
    function(){ //unhovered, 1000 milliseconds
        // set a timer to call the hide function
        timer = setTimeout("hide_function", 1000);
    }
);

$('content_tab_here').bind('mouseleave', function(){
    // hide it, you can set a timer here too if you want
});
```

Here is the docs on timer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
There are many options here but this will get you started, the jquery I used is old school so if you are using latest version of jquery you can change the code accordingly. I don't want to write out everything for you because then you won't be learning and I don't have that much time because I am at work. Good luck.

Comment: Just one more small problem: When not hovering over the content-div or another nav-tab after hovering over the desired nav-tab , it stays open/active. Like in a horizontal menu you hover over the 1st (most left) tab and then go out to the left. Your solution wont affect it...Do you need a jfiddle to understand what i mean?

Comment: either a fiddle or a picture would help, or the html code of how this thing nests.

Comment: it doesnt perfectly mirror my layout but i hope you get what the problem is. http://jsfiddle.net/WnQvF/27/

Comment: right i see what you are saying. my solution does not affect that, you have to capture the same event (mouseleave) for your tabs but if you got space between the tabs and the content then the content will disappear when you hover off the tabs
so depends on how you want to show this, you might need a timer for the content to disappear

Comment: Can you or anybody else give me an example on how to do this?